# multiple file upload laravel 5 and move to folder

Tags: image, laravel-5, image-uploading, move

I'm trying to upload multiple files and store the name in the database, and the file in the storage/thumbnail folder. The problem is that the move function is not working because the file that has to be moved is empty. However when I DD my results, all images show up.

here's my code:

```
$files = Input::file('images'); //The array with images
```

The loop to put all images to the storage folder:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    Input::file($file)->move('storage/thumb_nail');
}
```

When i dd($file) inside the loop it shows the image object like this:

```
UploadedFile {#30 ▼
   -test: false
   -originalName: "IMG_0180.JPG"
   -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
   -size: 1331799
   -error: 0
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

It didn't work because of the file name being not correctly passed it should've been like this:

```
$files = Input::file('images');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filename  = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = public_path('storage/thumb_nail/' . $filename);
        Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
        $file->image = 'storage/thumb_nail/'.$filename;
    }
```